# Log SQL Queries to File if MySQL DB Connection fails

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have a Perl script for writing data to a MySQL DB, runs fine.  Question I have is if there is a proper method to log prepared queries to a local file if the connection to the MySQL DB times out or fails?  If the connection fails or timeouts, does the Perl-DBI obj even allow preparing MySQL statements?

Thank you!

Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing like that built into DBI or the MySQL client.  It's hard to make it work correctly in a generic fashion, too, as many of the edge/exception cases really are application specific.

This sort of thing is also prone to error as you're doing something relatively complicated only when things are already going badly.  If MySQL being unavailable is a common case or it's too important to stop/timeout/retry in case of errors, see if you can write the data to another stream (always) that is better at handling errors.  For example you could push it into scribe on the local server and have another program read the data from scribe and insert/update MySQL.  Scribe takes care of the local buffering to disk and such.

Of course that just has different trade-offs in different error scenarios.

Comment: Excellent response.  Thank you!  The primary reason for this case is because the MySQL server is remote(over VPN).  I haven't experienced any issues with connectivity to the write DB, just want a plan if it were to happen.  I have it write to that MySQL server, and it reads from a local replica slave.  I use tungsten for the replication.  I know tungsten is supposed to support synchronizing several different database platforms.  I will have to check if it synchronizes scribe.

Comment: The way you'd use scribe (or maybe a dedicated/proper queuing/messaging tool like ActiveMQ or whatever people use) would be to write to the queue locally and then have a separate process read from the queue and insert/update the database.  Each write will get some extra latency, but your web application can be "done" with it quickly and it'll work (eventually) in case of network outages.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed the down-tick...odd.